# Looking for a teacher in Australia

Tags: teachers

If you live in Australia and can be my teacher please get in touch. I feel I'm at a stage where I need one. Or perhaps you can recommend someone for me?

Answer (score 2):

If you're in Western Australia, and interested in Theravada, the best teacher for you would be [Ajahn Brahm](https://bswa.org/teachers/ajahn-brahm/). You can find videos of his talks on the [Youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/BuddhistSocietyWA) of the [Buddhist Society of Western Australia (BSWA)](https://bswa.org/) and also [here](https://bswa.org/teachings/?teaching_topic=560&teacher=564). I don't reside in Australia, but I've attended Ajahn Brahm's talks when he visited my city. The next most senior monks at BSWA after Ajahn Brahm seem to be [Ajahn Appichato](https://bswa.org/teachers/ajahn-appichato/) and [Ajahn Brahmali](https://bswa.org/teachers/ajahn-brahmali/) who may also be helpful.

Although I am not familiar with him, if you stay in Victoria, [Ajahn Kalyano](https://buddhabodhivana.org/about/ajahn-kalyano/) of the [Buddha Bodhivana Monastery](https://buddhabodhivana.org/) can be your teacher. Here's a [Youtube video](https://youtu.be/-CduzLzUb0M) of one of his talks.

In New South Wales, there's the [Bodhisaddha Forest Monastery](https://www.bodhisaddha.org/wat/en/visiting/) (although I do not know who are the teachers there) and [Wat Buddha Dhamma](http://www.wbd.org.au/about-wbd/location/) (whose [abbot](http://www.wbd.org.au/about-wbd/community/) seems to be [Ajahn Khemavaro](https://bswa.org/teachers/ajahn-khemavaro/)). Perhaps, Ajahn Khemavaro can be your teacher. Here's a [Youtube video](https://youtu.be/kyi3KgdwueI) of his talk. Here's [another talk](https://youtu.be/OtVTw9g55kU) from him.

The teachers and monasteries above are all from the [Thai Forest Tradition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thai_Forest_Tradition), of the lineage of [Ajahn Chah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajahn_Chah). There may be other monasteries from this tradition in other parts of Australia.

Comment: Hi Ruben, I'm in Sydney but I like Ajahn Brahm and Thai forest tradition is pretty much what I practice. I wasn't sure if someone like him could be a personal teacher as I thought he would be too busy maybe?

Comment: @Arturia I updated my answer. Perhaps, Ajahn Khemavaro at the Wat Buddha Dhamma (1 hour 45 minutes from Sydney) could be your teacher. The Bodhisaddha Forest Monastery is 1 hour away from Sydney but I don't know who are the teachers there. Both monasteries are of the Thai Forest Tradition.

Comment: So can I just go there and say "hi can you be my teacher" ?  This is what I'm unsure about. Is there a protocol to these things? Do I need to attend and get to know people first or just go there and ask?

Comment: Just email Wat BuddhaDhamma and say you wish to visit and receive some instruction. I visited last year, when I was visiting my mother. I hired a car and drove up. When they email you, they will tell you the combination of the padlock. You have to drive up a dirt road for about 30 minutes but its an excellent road. I merely had a small hire car and it was raining heavily. The road is well-maintained because there are major electrical power lines in the area that must be serviced by the govt. Its a very beautiful place; with many old accommodations.

Comment: In a talk, Ajahn Brahm once said that he visited various monasteries and teachers. Most were stoic or gloomy. But Ajahn Chah and his monks were smiling and happy. Ajahn Brahm thought they must be doing something right and felt that he would fit right in. You may need to explore and get to know teachers, before choosing one.

Answer (score 2):

[Patrick Kearney](http://www.dharmasalon.net/) is a Mahasi teacher in NSW Australia.

> *"Patrick Kearney is the best mindfulness teacher it has been my experience to work with. I appreciate the depth of his insights into
>   the Buddha’s teaching, meanings that have resonated with me
>   personally. Few teachers can help smooth a student’s own experience
>   with mindfulness practice as he does. Last, and hardly least, Patrick
>   has a huge heart, and this manifests in all his teachings. I cannot
>   recommend a workshop with Patrick Kearney highly enough."*

Comment: Hi, yes I did a retreat with him. He was very good. i guess what I need to know is how do I approach someone to ask. Can I just send an email and say hi I need a teacher?

Comment: Sure. Just send him an email asking for assistance and instruction.